# python for-in -> if not in -> if -> del process stops working for no reason

Tags: python, nlp

I tried to delete words from a list using the conditions as below.
but for some reason, in the middle of second condition, the logic stops working.

logic is as below.

1. iterate words in a list
2. if the words has '-' and the word having '-' is not a member of exception group
3. count how many '-' the word has
4. if the word has only one '-'

   - split the word into two part, one is before '-' the other is after '-'
   - then replace the word with '-' with the two new words above "before hyphen"
     and "after hyphen"
5. if the word has two '-'

   - do the similar thing as step 4 but splitting into three parts and replace
     the word with two hyphens '-' with three part of word
     "before first hyphen", "between two hyphen", "after hyphen"

---

I finally came up with the logic and wrote the code as below.

```
z = ['blue-ray','red-ray-something', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']
exception =['olive-oil','canola-oil']

# for entity in z:
#     print(entity)
# z[1] in save_dash
for entity in z:
    print(entity)
    if '-' in entity and entity not in exception:
        print(entity)
        letter_count=Counter(entity)
        
        if letter_count['-']==2:  
            print('hi')
            first_hyphen=entity.index('-')
            second_hyphen=find_nth(entity,'-',2)
            firstword = entity[:first_hyphen]
            secondword= entity[first_hyphen+1:second_hyphen]
            thirdword = entity[second_hyphen+1:]
            delete_index = z.index(entity)
            del z[delete_index]
            z.append(firstword)
            z.append(secondword)
            z.append(thirdword)
        elif letter_count['-']==1:   
            print('no')
            hyphenindex=entity.index('-')
            firstword = entity[:hyphenindex]
            secondword= entity[hyphenindex+1:]
#             delete_index = z.index(entity)
#             del z[delete_index]
#             z.append(firstword)
#             z.append(secondword)
```

No error but as soon as I un-commentout from

> "delete_index = z.index(entity)"

the word with two hyphens stop being sorted out.

Why is that?

Comment: This is a lot of code to try and debug, but I'll note that it's a bad idea to modify the structure of a data structure while iterating over it, which you're doing by deleting and appending to `z` while iterating it. You should create a new list that's based on a copy of `z`, then `append`/`del` from it instead. You're likely "confusing" the iterator, and causing elements to get missed by the iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included the "find_nth" function to let others run this piece of code. Can you add that in please?

Aside, can I suggest using string.partition to separate the string at the hypen?

```
keyword = "-"
before_keyword, keyword, after_keyword = entity.partition(keyword)

#Example
#'red-ray-something'.partition("-")
# ('red', '-', 'ray-something')
```

Here is some alternative code to achieve the same thing for any number of hypens.
I've used two separate lists. Deleting items from a list while iterating through it is not a good idea. That's probably why it's skipping items.

```
z = ['blue-ray','red-ray-something', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red','ble-ray-tfr-gtd','blu-ray']
exception =['olive-oil','canola-oil']

new_z = []


for entity in z:
    print(entity)
    if '-' in entity and entity not in exception:
        number_of_hypens = entity.count("-")
        keyword = "-"
        for i in range(number_of_hypens+1):
            before_keyword, keyword, after_keyword = entity.partition(keyword)
            new_z.append(before_keyword)
            entity = after_keyword
    else:
        new_z.append(entity)
        
print(z)
print(new_z)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Carcigenicate already explained, you usually can't loop through a list and remove items from the list at the same time or add items.

This code should do what you want:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    z = ['blue-ray','red-ray-something', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']
    exception =['olive-oil','canola-oil']
    new_z = [word.split('-') if word not in exception else [word] for word in z]
    print(new_z)
    # Make 1D list again
    flat_list = [item for sublist in new_z for item in sublist]
    print(flat_list)
```

Output:

```
[['blue', 'ray'], ['red', 'ray', 'something'], ['blue'], ['yellow'], ['blue'], ['red']]
['blue', 'ray', 'red', 'ray', 'something', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']
```